# Override UID GID in VSCode Remote-containers session

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am running VSCode in a Windows 10 machine, connecting to a Docker instance on a remote Linux host, to develop C++ projects. The docker instance mounts local folders for source code files, and user is set to match the user on Linux host to avoid file ownership and permission problems.

On Windows 10 I use WSL1, the default user has both UID/GID 1000, and the VSCode's docker processes use these IDs to launch and connect to the docker instance on remote. Is there a way to override the UID/GID VSCode uses so they match the IDs on remote?

Thanks,

```html
Step 1/4 : FROM devenv:latest
---> 120d987bae07
Step 2/4 : RUN groupadd -g 301765 chengd
---> Using cache
---> 58a697ed3565
Step 3/4 : RUN useradd -l -u 301765 -g chengd chengd
---> Using cache
---> b5c7c2b48a83
Step 4/4 : USER chengd
---> Using cache
---> f310c9d1e05b
Successfully built f310c9d1e05b
Successfully tagged vsc-devenv-9da1a5f5cedc16a80d314a148acdbcaf:latest
[7325 ms] Start: Run: wsl -d Ubuntu-20.04 -e /bin/sh -c cd '/home/da/repos/devenv' && DISPLAY='1' ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE='1' SSH_ASKPASS='d:\Users\ChengD\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.177.2\scripts\ssh-askpass.bat' VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_NODE='D:\Users\ChengD\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe' VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_MAIN='d:\Users\ChengD\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.177.2\dist\common\sshAskpass.js' VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_HANDLE='\\.\pipe\ssh-askpass-7e8e4f69496930d0e88509584ba46ab3357d9ff1-sock' DOCKER_CONTEXT='tcp_201' VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_COUNTER='5' docker 'inspect' '--type' 'image' 'vsc-devenv-9da1a5f5cedc16a80d314a148acdbcaf'
[10240 ms] Start: Run: wsl -d Ubuntu-20.04 -e /bin/sh -c cd '/home/da/repos/devenv' && DISPLAY='1' ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE='1' SSH_ASKPASS='d:\Users\ChengD\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.177.2\scripts\ssh-askpass.bat' VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_NODE='D:\Users\ChengD\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe' VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_MAIN='d:\Users\ChengD\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.177.2\dist\common\sshAskpass.js' VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_HANDLE='\\.\pipe\ssh-askpass-7e8e4f69496930d0e88509584ba46ab3357d9ff1-sock' DOCKER_CONTEXT='tcp_201' VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_COUNTER='6' docker 'build' '-f' '/tmp/vsch/updateUID.Dockerfile-0.177.2' '-t' 'vsc-devenv-9da1a5f5cedc16a80d314a148acdbcaf-uid' '--build-arg' 'BASE_IMAGE=vsc-devenv-9da1a5f5cedc16a80d314a148acdbcaf' '--build-arg' 'REMOTE_USER=chengd' '--build-arg' 'NEW_UID=1000' '--build-arg' 'NEW_GID=1000' '--build-arg' 'IMAGE_USER=chengd' '/tmp/vsch'
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem by setting updateRemoteUserUID to false in devcontainer.json.